# How to update an Account field using a Trigger on Account

Tags: apex, trigger, account

```
trigger AccountStatusOverrideTrigger on Account (before insert, before update, before delete) {
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
   accountIds.add(acc.Id);
}

List<Account> accounts = [select Client_Account_Status_Override__c from account where id in: accountIds];

for(Account a : accounts) {        
    a.Client_Account_Status__c = a.Client_Account_Status_Override__c;
}   

update accounts;
}
```

That's all I have done, but it's giving an error about recursive call on itself.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to query for the records or update them. Remove everything but your `for` loop:

```
trigger AccountStatusOverrideTrigger on Account (before insert, before update, before delete) {
    for(Account a : trigger.new) {        
        a.Client_Account_Status__c = a.Client_Account_Status_Override__c;
    }   
}
```

Note that you can accomplish this via `Workflow Rule` or `Process Builder`. Using an `Apex Trigger` for such simple functionality is overkill.

Comment: `Apex trigger AccountOverrideTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AccountOverrideTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001R000000twXB0IAM; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AccountOverrideTrigger: maximum trigger depth exceeded Account trigger event AfterUpdate for `

Comment: Trying out your code gave that error. AdrianLarson

Comment: @DIPXOID The trigger outlined in my post should not, on its own, cause that error. Take a look at your `Workflow Rules` and flows in `Process Builder` and see which ones might be causing the recursion.

Comment: Probably, I just remember a trigger on Opportunity updates same field. How can I use this Trigger as the second option to  trigger @AdrianLarson

Comment: @DIPXOID Seriously get this out of triggers. Try to build it all using `Process Builder` instead. Good learning experience and way easier to build/maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Theres no need to query the accounts directly in the trigger- those are provided inside of the trigger context, and are accessible via `Trigger.new`. You can read more about trigger context variables [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).

You will also need to remove the `update accounts;` line. You are trying to update the records which are currently in the process of being updated by the trigger itself- which calls the trigger, which calls the trigger, and so on. Direct modifications to the objects inside of the `Trigger.new` list in a `before update` trigger will be saved into the database, if the trigger executes successfully.

Comment: Don't forget, though, that you need to set the field values on the *context* references to the records. The query changes the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Being a 'before insert' trigger, you don't need to do call `update accounts`. The DML will happen after the trigger runs. But I think your logic is flawed and not doing what you'd like it to do. Why don't you tell us more about what you want to do?

Comment: Don't forget, though, that you need to set the field values on the *context* references to the records. The query changes the reference.

Comment: You expressed it very elegantly. That's what I meant by the 'flawed logic' mention above.